# Woocommerce: Create short-code with parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a short-code to get products from specific category in woocommerce. I am using 'tax_query' to target specific category and 'shortcode_atts' to get parameter from shortcode itself. The code is as follow:

```
function quick_launch_products($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'product_category_ID' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => '12',
        'meta_query'            => array(
            array(
                'key'           => '_visibility',
                'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                'compare'       => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'field'         => 'term_id',
                'terms'         => $product_category_ID,
                'operator'      => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );

    echo $product_category_ID;

    $products = null;
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
}        
add_shortcode("quick_launch_product_slider", "quick_launch_products");
```

The shortcode:

```
[quick_launch_product_slider product_category_ID="383"]
```

The return value is blank. I saw a lot of demo codes and followed exactly as they were, but its not working at all.

What am i missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have returned before you used argument ? really !!!

Comment: What you mean? @Alice

Comment: @mysticalghoul Alice means that "return $product_category_ID;" this statement will never let the code work that is after it.

Comment: OK, i removed return and replaced it with echo and the result is the same

Comment: So, if your "$product_category_ID" is empty, then you will never be able to query the products correctly. You should check that first.

Comment: Here also you are echoing $product_category_ID only, but if the line '$products = new WP_Query($args);' produced some line still you have not printed them at all.